# How are person curves created?

Tags: curves, parametric, wolfram-alpha

One can graph some person curves such as [Joe Biden curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=graph%20joe%20biden%20curve) and [Kim Jung Un Curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=graph+kim+jong+un+curve) using WolframAlpha. I am curious how these curves were created using parametric equations.

[image]

Comment: I assume that they're just drawing a picture, and then running it through a polygon/curve tracing program (like you'd use to digitize a font from raster images of the characters) to turn it into equations.  It would certainly be hard to find these equations by hand.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) from the folks at Wolfram, as well as this neat segment from a [3B1B video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k&t=850s)

Comment: You can also search for Desmos Art...